# Screen record through ADB error

Tags: android, adb

Trying to do a screen record on my Note 3 which is running  4.4.2 onto my internal memory. I don't have an MicroSD card.

`adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/example.mp4`

Is this the correct command to use? It returns an error saying:

`WARNING: linker: libsavscmn.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your command is the right one to use. It seems to be a Samsung error, I haven't seen this issues on other devices than a Samsung.

Are you saying the screen record is not done? Ignore this warning.

Comment: Silly me, it was recording. Just that it has this warning message which I thought it didn't even started